# JQuery trouble accessing next of target element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0oxy2wg/6/)

I can't figure out why, but if in the fiddle above if you type any character into the input followed by the down key, the console makes two logs. The first is a value of `3` (correct) and the second is a value of `0` (incorrect).

I'm trying to target the element following a specific input:

```
// this works...
console.log($('.autocomplete li').length);
// this does not work
console.log($(this).next('.autocomplete li').length);
```

If I just log `$(this)` it returns `input` as expected. I've also tried `.nextAll`, `.find` and various combinations.

Why isn't it finding the `.next` element of the target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the `.autocomplete` that is `next` to `this`, not the `li`. So the filter will not work.

Instead, you would need to use `$(this).next('.autocomplete').find('li')`

However, have you considered a JS-free solution?

```html
<input type="text" list="options" />
<datalist id="options"> <!-- ^-- Same identifier -->
  <option>America</option>
  <option>Europe</option>
  <option>Japan</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I know it's off-topic from this question, but is there a trick to getting `datalist` to work when it's dynamically populated from an AJAX request?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
console.log($(this).next('.autocomplete').find('li').length);
```

You need to target the next `.autocomplete` and find the `li`.